# I can't get id of a image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the id of my img in javascript on a mousewheel but when I do a getElementById I it tells me that the length is null

this is the function where I put my img

```
function parse_data(data)
{
 var json = data;
 var obj = JSON.parse(json);
 var buff = "";

 for(var i in obj)
 {
  //document.write('<br>' + i + '<br>');                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  for (var j in obj[i])
  {
        if (obj[i][j] == true)
          buff += "<a href=\"#\" onmousewheel=\"test()\" ><img id=\"obj[i]\" src=\"../images/pix_green.jpg\" border=\"0\" /></a>";
        else
          buff += "<a href=\"#\" onmousewheel=\"test()\" ><img id=\"obj[i]\" src=\"../images/pix_gray.jpg\" border=\"0\" /></a>";
  }
    buff += "<br>";
 }
  document.getElementById('frisekk').innerHTML = buff;
}
```

And this is the function where I want to get back the id of an img on mousewheel

```
function test()
{
  var obj = document.getElementById('img');

  alert(obj.length); //obj.length is null...
  if (event.wheelDelta >= 120)
    unit -= 60;
  else
    unit += 60;
 request(readData);
}
```

how could I get the id of my img ?

there is all the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Techniques AJAX - XMLHttpRequest</title>
<script>
 var unit = 60;
 var date = 'Mon Oct 20 2014 19:25:00 GMT (CET)';

 function request(callback)
 {
  var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();
  var frise = 600;
  var template = 'lab';

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
   if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0))
    callback(xhr.responseText);
  };

  xhr.open("GET", "a.php?Frise=" + frise + "&Unit=" + unit + "&Template=" + template + "&Date=" + date, true);
  xhr.send(null);
}

function readData(sData)
{
 parse_data(sData);
}

function parse_data(data)
{
 var json = data;
 var obj = JSON.parse(json);
 var buff = "";
 for(var i in obj)
 {
   //document.write('<br>' + i + '<br>');                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   for (var j in obj[i])
   {
      //document.write(j + "=" + obj[i][j] + '<br>');                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      if (obj[i][j] == true)
        buff += "<a href=\"#\" onmousewheel=\"test()\" ><img id=\"obj[i]\" src=\"../images/pix_green.jpg\" border=\"0\" /></a>";
      else
        buff += "<a href=\"#\" onmousewheel=\"test()\" ><img id=\"obj[i]\" src=\"../images/pix_gray.jpg\" border=\"0\" /></a>";
    }
   buff += "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById('frisekk').innerHTML = buff;
}

function test()
{
 var obj = document.getElementById('img');
 alert(obj.length);
 if (event.wheelDelta >= 120)
   unit -= 60;
 else
   unit += 60;
 request(readData);
}

</script>


<script>
function getXMLHttpRequest()
{
 var xhr = null;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
   if (window.ActiveXObject)
   {
     try 
     {
      xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
     } 
     catch(e)
     {
      xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
    } 
    else 
    {
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
   }
   else 
   {
    alert("Votre navigateur ne supporte pas l'objet XMLHTTPRequest...");
    return null;
   }
  return xhr;
 }
</script>
<span id="frisekk"> <br/> </span>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<p>
<input type="button" onclick="request(readData);" value="Exécuter" />
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `img` the id of the image? Are you sure it has `<img id="img">`?

Comment: Could you please, post the html generated? to check the id as @ekad  told you in the last comment

Comment: The id of the image is obj[i] that containe like 1456058 it depends on the  json that I catch

Comment: Also not sure `obj[i]` should be used as an id, if `obj[i][j]` exists then `obj[i]` as to be an object when one would expect a string as a valid id attribute. And yeah it's `getElementsByTagName('img')` then length should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById` does not get the *id* for you, it gets the element by id passed. Since you didn't post your HTML I can't really say whether your `<img />` tag has the id of `img`, but I'm assuming not. What you are looking for is `document.getElementsByTagName('img')` to get tevery img element on the page and then use a loop to find which one you need (or add `[0]` if you know you only have one to select the first element).

So you have two options:

1. Add an ID to your element (best option)

`<img src="path/to/image.jpg" id="my_image" />
var finalElement = document.getElementById("my_image");`

2. Find all elements with the tagname 'img' and then search through them for the right on

`<img src="path/to/image.jpg" />
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var finalElement = false;
    for(var i = elements.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
        // match your element and return
        if(/* criteria */){
            finalElement = elements[i];
            break;
        }
    }`

3. Have only one image on your page and select that:

`<img src="path/to/image.jpg" id="my_image" />
var finalElement = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];`

### Update

Your `onmousewheel` property could be supported, but then you need to do it slightly differently, because your link has the `onmousewheel` event.

```
<!-- add the 'this' keyword to your test() function to pass the <a> element -->
<a href="#" onmousewheel="test(this)"><img src="path/to/image.jpg" /></a>
```

With this structure (one `<img>` nested in an `<a>`), you can pass the `<a>` to the function using the `this`keyword.

```
/* Add a variable to receive your <a> in your test() function. */
function test(link){
    /* Use childNodes[0] to select the first child element of the a. */
    var image = link.childNodes[0];
    /* Will alert '1' if the <a> has a child, will alert '0' if the <a> is empty.*/
    alert(image.length);
}
```

Now you can easily access the only child of the a element, the image, and do something with that.

I am not sure whether onmousehweel is supported on an  element, so pelase consider an `onclick` or `onmouseover` to test this function. If you decide to test with `onmouseover`, use the `console.log` to log instead of `alert`, otherwise you'll drown in alerts.

Comment: The best would be `onmousewheel=\"test(obj[i])\"` because I need the obj[i] of the img when the user will do a mousewheel on the img. But it dosn't work.

Comment: @leykan Check my update to see how you could still access the `<img />` element nested in your `<a>`, even though you are performing the `onmousewheel` on the `<a>`

Comment: It tell me `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` but is it possible instead of passing the img to pass in onmousewheel="test(obj[i])" ? beacause I need more the obj[i] that the img

Comment: Woops, indeed `childNodes()` is not a function. I have amended it to `childNodes[0]`, which should work. I also changed the word `object`, it doesnt make a different but its safer since object is reserved as a word in some isntances. I've tested this and it works.

Comment: It works but if I put `id="obj[i]"` it will print me `obj[i]` instead of the value of `obj[i]` is it possible to to put the value of the `obj[i]` ?

Comment: @leykan I have no idea why you are doing this! Anything surrounded by `"` or `'` are _strings_ and will be treated as such! The value stored in my `image` variable is the same value you were expecting to get with your `document.getElementById("img")`, namely the DOM object itself! You don't have to use the ID. There isn't a use for the ID in this circumstance unless you use it for CSS. So after doing the above, do this to mimic what you had : `alert(image.length);`. Check changes, I added comments.

Comment: @leykan if this is correct, could you mark it as such? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Can't you parse the id in the function call?
Eg in:

```
onmousewheel=test(obj[i])
```

and in the `function,`

```
function test(id)??
```

Comment: It tells me "Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined"